# matching data type in clojure with core.match/match instead of multimethod

Tags: clojure, core.match

Ho can I have this type matching work. (I am using `clojure.core.match/match`). Or is `multimethod` the only way to go.

```
(let [x "1.2"]
  (match [(read-string x)]
         [^java.lang.Long l] :long
         [^java.lang.Double d] :double
         :else :string))

>> :long
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with a normal `condp`

```
(let [x "1.2"]
  (condp = (type (read-string x))
    java.lang.Long :long
    java.lang.Double :double
    :string))
```